# ReactJs Antd dropdown collapses in localhost after some changes

Tags: reactjs, caching, dropdown, antd

In reactjs app, i'm using the antd for dropdown. When I am doing some development it collapses. Then I cleared the npm and deleted all my changes but still the dropdown collapses., It is the issue in all dropdowns over the app.

I again installed the fresh copy from git still the same issue.

Reactjs(Frontend), Expressjs (Middleware and Backend)

I am using the redis caching system. I also cleared the cache in redis still the same issue.

Before
[image]

After doing some code changes and reverted the changes. Also installed as fresh copy from git. Still it does not get resolved.
[image]

I am stuck on this and I am very new to this one, pls help me and any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you clear browser cache/data and checked?

Comment: @Ved I have completely disabled the cache in firefox and chrome. And also I have changed the port after fresh installation still the same error.

Comment: Did you inspect the element in the browser and checked the CSS?

Comment: @Ved I checked in both staging env and local. Both the css are same. The only difference I can see in HTML is aria-expanded="false" in the local env which is a faulty one now.

Comment: Posting some code on this section of the page might be helpful to check where the problems are.

Comment: @Anthony220 not only this page. all the pages having same issue.

Comment: Can you please post some piece of code here, so that I can get into issue more better.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to know without any code but have you tried forcing the drop down to be open via props, would help in knowing if it's an issue with UI rendering or logic bug.